# empty props Object.keys in React Redux rest-api

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to map / convert object from props in React. Data is coming from rest-api library and to component via mapStateToProps.

But when i try to use Object.keys its empty

```
    console.log('storagesTree', this.props.storagesTree);
    console.log('data', this.props.storagesTree.data);
    let items = Object.keys(this.props.storagesTree.data);
    console.log('length', items.length);
```

Below console report screen

[image]

#### UPDATE

this is my raw data from api:

```
{"@context":"\/admin\/api\/user_storages","@type":"UserStoragesList","user":"5eb2a2ae37f018528939f883","groups":{},"storages":{"first":{"create":true,"read":true,"update":true,"delete":true},"second":{"create":true,"read":true,"update":true,"delete":true}}}
```

file with fetching data from rest via redux-api library

```
import "isomorphic-fetch";
import reduxApi, {transformers} from "redux-api";
import adapterFetch from "redux-api/lib/adapters/fetch";

export default reduxApi({
  storagesTree: {data: {}},

  userInfo: {
    url: `/admin/api/user_storages_test`,
    postfetch: [

      function({data, getState}) {
        let {storagesTree} = getState();

        for(const storage in data.storages) {
          if(data.storages[storage].read === true) {
            storagesTree.data[storage] = {};
          }
        }

      }
    ]
  }

}).use("rootUrl", "http://localhost:84").use("fetch", adapterFetch(fetch));
```

and my component, where i trying to use Object.keys

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class StoragesTree extends Component {

    render() {

        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.storagesTree.data, null, 3))
        
        console.log('storagesTree', this.props.storagesTree);
        console.log('data', this.props.storagesTree.data);
        var items = Object.keys(this.props.storagesTree.data);
        console.log('lengths', items.length);

        return (
            <div>
                <div>StoragesTree</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const { userInfo, storagesTree } = state

    return {
        userInfo,
        storagesTree,
      }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(StoragesTree)
```

Comment: In your case it should print the output length as 2, right? And what is the output when you print just `items`?

Comment: Can you please add more of your code? In the parts you've added I don't see a problem. Maybe you could create a minimal example at [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io). I think it's probably an async. issue but with-out seeing your code I can only guess.

Comment: @AWolf, exactly. I think this is an async issue as well.

Comment: yes, data comming from asyc, exacly from rest-api library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-api); please give me few minutes to update my question with some coce

Comment: question updated

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan yes, length should be 2, console.log(items); give me empty array with length 0